# Undefined result in Console by Input to Array Fields

Tags: javascript, html

Why when I pus the Submit button is undefined all of them?

I want to create an array just by using input fields like this.

Is there a nother way to do this?

I tried to do it with Class name and the result is still undefined

```js
function clicked() {
    var input_value = document.querySelectorAll('#data, #data1, #data2, #data3, #data4').value;
    console.log(input_value)
}

document.getElementById('btn').addEventListener('click', clicked);
```

```html
<input id="data">
<input id="data1">
<input id="data2">
<input id="data3">
<input id="data4">
<button id="btn">Click me</button>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`querySelectorAll` will return a "NodeList", which is similar to an array. NodeLists don't have a `value` property, so it's returning undefined.

If you want to get the value from each of the input boxes, you'll need to loop through the NodeList and pull the `value` from each HTML element individually.

```
function clicked() {
    var nodeList = document.querySelectorAll('#data, #data1, #data2, #data3, #data4');
    for (var i = 0; i < nodeList.length; i++) {
      console.log(nodeList[i].value);
    }
}

document.getElementById('btn').addEventListener('click', clicked);
```

Comment: I want it to return a pure array in console

Answer (score 0):

Change fn to this:

```
function clicked() {
  var inputs= document.querySelectorAll('#data, #data1, #data2, #data3, #data4');
  inputs.forEach(i => {
    console.log(i.value);
  });
}
```